# vendor name show in product box in nop commerce in homepage

Tags: nopcommerce, nopcommerce-themes

show vendor name in Product Box. vendor name show in product detail page working perfectly.but not show in product box partial view. i don't know Nop commerce how to manage this.

Comment: you must create a plugin and override_productbox partialview via this plugin. it is not that hard. just see the articles how to create a plugin

Comment: @batmaci what is controller and action name of product box

Comment: It should be productcontroller and productbox